# Can React Testing Library find element after state change?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm absolutely new to react testing, learning from a playlist in youtube.

In [this very moment of the tutorial](https://youtu.be/V2wWLM8VX5k?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gm4_-5UsNmLqMosM-dzuvQ&t=487), the instructor tests a component, which:

1. has a useEffect.
2. inside a useEffect, there is an `axios.get`
3. state is updated with api response.
4. state data is turned to elements (each has `data-testid` attribute equal to `follower-item-{someNumber}`.

The objective of the test is to find a data element.
. despite that i'm almost coping his code, his test passes, but mine doesn't. seems like the test runs before data fetching.

**the component:**

```
export default function FollowersList() {
  const [followers, setFollowers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFollowers();
  }, []);
  const fetchFollowers = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5");
    setFollowers(data.results);
  };

  return (
    <div className="followerslist-container">
      <div>
        {followers.map((follower, ind) => (
          <div className="follower-item" data-testid={`follower-item-${ind}`}>
            <img src={follower.picture.large} />
            <div className="followers-details">
              <div className="follower-item-name">
                <h4>{follower.name.first}</h4> <h4>{follower.name.last}</h4>
              </div>
              <p>{follower.login.username}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="todo-footer">
        <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The test:**

```
const MockFollowersList = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <FollowersList />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

describe("followers list", () => {
  it("should render follower items", async () => {
    render(<MockFollowersList />);
    let el = await screen.findByTestId("follower-item-0");

    expect(el).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**result:**

```
 Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="follower-item-0"]

<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="followerslist-container"
    >
      <div />
      <div
        class="todo-footer"
      >
        <a
          href="/"
        >
          Go Back
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does ` await waitFor(() => {(getByTestId('follower-item-0')).toBeInTheDocument()})` work for you?

Comment: no success unfortunately. seems like the test runs before data fetching.

Comment: I think you could give it a fake array at the first run with the id 0 just to let it be found at the first run , I mean do not initialise the array with ```EMPTY```, cause when it search for the id on first run it found ```undefined```

Comment: but in this case you wont really test the nedeed case exactly , I mean the test is runing before the data is filled 

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't mock data. Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock#debugging or something similar.

I recommend you to install and use eslint rule for testing library: https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library. This rule could help you avoid a common mistakes.